# how do I resolve the "waydroid session is stopped" problem?

Tags: command-line, bash, android

I tried to install an apk app after I installed, configured and initialized waydroid, I get this:

```
[12:59:33] WayDroid session is stopped
```

should I reinstall it? or there's something wrong with the initialization? How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: How does this relate to Ubuntu ?

Comment: Well, Waydroid does run on Ubuntu, so it is possibly on topic.

Comment: I am using ubuntu, simple

Comment: I've just got the same problem. I don't see any solution here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, I was root but I should have been a normal user.

Some commands **need root** to work:

```
sudo waydroid container start
```

Others need to be **common user** to work:

```
waydroid app install <filename>.apk
```

Make sure you are using the correct user in the terminal, or it will always return: "WayDroid session is stopped".

If problem persists, *restart terminal* and try again.

Comment: Yeah but how do you make sure you are using the correct user? Which user is the correct user? Do we need to add the current user to a usergroup to make the current user the correct user? The reason I ask is because, I used my current user to set up and install Waydroid. I also used su to change to the other user on my computer and the other user also produced the same result.

Comment: However the container start command reports that the "WayDroid container service is already running" and systemctl also reports that the status of waydroid.container is indeed active (running). And I've also tried restarting the service through systemd and even without sudo so that systemd would prompt for the password instead and also possibly link the session and permissions to the current user.

Comment: So, it turns out that waydroid is not compatible with X11. However, after logging into a Wayland session on Gnome Shell (I did confirm Wayland after logging in), I still get the same "WayDroid session is stopped", even though it also reports that it's running.